# C# (HTML razor Display)

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

So i have been having this problem for a while, My API returns all the specified data out from my giving model

```
 public class FooterModel
{
    public FooterModel()
    {

    }

    public string Adresse { get; set; }
    public string PostNr { get; set; }
    public string TelefonNummer { get; set; }
    public string E_mail { get; set; }

    public List<OpeningHourModel> openingHours { get; set; }

    public class OpeningHourModel
    {
        public string DayOfWeekName { get; set; }

        public int DayOfWeekNumber { get; set; }

        public DateTime From { get; set; }

        public DateTime To { get; set; }

        public bool IsClosed { get; set; }

        public bool IsOpenAllDay { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Yet when i try to Display it in a HTML page using Razor, I'm having trouble displaying my List "openingsHour" in My HTML page, its only displaying some of the data.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.openingHours)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

I'm only getting the string value "DayOfWeekName".

Consider this is Umbraco and with that Application I'm using my Model as a IEnumerable

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IEnumerable<UmbracoWebsite.Models.FooterModel>>
```

Comment: Why does your question title tell us nothing of your problem?

Comment: Take a look at this (asp.net partials) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2. This allows you to do @Html.Partial("yourpartialname", item), and within the partial declare @model OpeningHourModel  and create the proper html / set properties there.

Comment: Hey John, its dosn't? Well i do apologize for any inconvenience, I'm complete new to stack overflow and forum posting in generel, but i will try to be more specific next time :) (i presume i should just edit the title?)

Comment: Hey usselite, i will try your solution, thanks for answering to my problem